# Static IP on DDWRT firmware

Tags: networking, dd-wrt, static-ip

I have a range of 8 static public IP's given to me by BT and I've recently upgraded my BT business hub to a Buffalo Airstation running DDWRT.
So far I've setup the router to obtain a dynamic IP, however I want to setup a single server on the network with It's own static IP address. I figured out how to do it on the BTHub, but can't figure it out on the new router. I'd like to keep the whole network NAT'ed and *not have to purchase two routers if possible*.

In the BT business hub I had it setup as follows (IP's Censored for security):

```
 Router Address: 111.11.111.118
 Subnet Mask: 255:255:255:248
 Allow Ping: Yes.
```

Then on the Server ifconfig was setup as follows:

```
 eth0    inet addr:111.11.111.113    Bcast:111.11.111.119     Mask:255.255.255.248
 lo        inet addr:127.0.0.1            Mask:255.0.0.0
```

I'm not entirely sure of what to configure on the DDWRT firmware to mimmic this setup

So far I've taken a guess and configured "Advanced Routing" as follows:

```
 Operating Mode: Gateway
 Set Number: 1 (Server)
 Route Name: Server
 Metric: 1
 Destination LAN NET: 111.11.111.113
 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.248
 Gateway: 111.11.111.118
 Interface: WAN
```

I've also disabled the firewall temporally for testing, and forwarded port 80 and 448.

And as you can probably guess, I'm having no luck whatsoever. When I try and access the IP, Safari returns "The server where this page is located isn't responding"

It's probably way off track, but I'm brand new to networking so please go easy. If anyone has any ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

- Update - Still no luck with this, does anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar problem about a week ago, I solved it by setting up One-to-One NAT on DDWRT and it worked perfectly. Here's the official Wiki guide I used. http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/One-to-one_NAT Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the MAC address of the server, you should be able to give it a static IP in DD-WRT (Services tab, and you'll see a DHCP Server section, in there there is an option to add a reservation).

Then go to the server, release and renew the IP address, make sure it gets the correct one, then you should be set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Anit,
I've tried setting the Server MAC to a static lease but it hasn't fixed the problem. I set the IP to the Server eth0 inetaddr from ifconfig and the lease time as infinite, then rebooted both the server and the router, is that right?

Comment: Try setting a DHCP reservation (as said in my answer above) for the server in DD-WRT. Make sure to press save, then "apply settings", which actually saves it and reboots the router.

On the server, make sure it is set for DHCP, and it SHOULD get the IP you told it to. Don't set the static IP on the server. Restart the server too, as the router is restarting.

Comment: Would this work if I set the static lease on the router to the external Static IP? e.g; 111.11.111.113 ?